# How can i code Zapier to follow a link that was provided in an email?

Tags: javascript, python, zapier

I am using Mailparser to scrape a booking email, then use Zapier to create a booking in our system.

In the email is a link to confirm the booking so am wanting to use the code action to click on the link or follow the link.

Nothing needs to be seen, just follow the link & allow the page to load. This confirms the reservation

I have attempted using python & JS to no avail.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Can you provide an example of the link?

Answer (score 2):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

When you click on a link and it opens in your browser, all that *really* is is a GET request. If the site you're trying to load is simple, then this can be accomplished with a `Webhook by Zapier` step that make the request to the provided URL.

The big issue that'll pop up is if the site is more complex. A browser loads and execute all the javascript on the page, which our GET request *won't* do. If the site uses javascript to confirm the reservation (not just the page loading itself), then this isn't going to work. If that's the case, it's a lot more involved. You'd probably need to make a CLI app and use a tool like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) that can load pages and everything in them. Note that I haven't tested that on the CLI and there's a chance it's incompatible with the way we run apps, so do a proof of concept before you really dive in.

Hope this helps. ​Let me know if you've got any other questions!

Comment: Thanks very much, David. Appreciate it!

Comment: No problem! Make sure to mark this answer as correct if it answered your question ([info](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).